# VS Code Key Binding for quick switch between terminal screens?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to set up a key binding to allow a quick switch between the terminal windows I have open in the built in terminal rather than having to click on the drop down selector each time. Does anyone know the command for this when making a personal key binding or where I can see a list of all the possible commands for VSC? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [Microsofts Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) there is a tip:

> Tip: If you use multiple terminals extensively, you can add key
>   bindings for the focusNext, focusPrevious and kill commands outlined
>   in the Key Bindings section to allow navigation between them using
>   only the keyboard.

From [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_key-bindings):

> Other terminal commands are available and can be bound to your
>   preferred keyboard shortcuts. They are:
>   workbench.action.terminal.focus: Focus the terminal. This is like
>   toggle but focuses the terminal instead of hiding it, if it is
>   visible.

```
workbench.action.terminal.focusNext: Focuses the next terminal instance. 
workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious: Focuses the previous terminal instance. 
workbench.action.terminal.kill: Remove the current terminal instance.
workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText: Run the selected text in the terminal instance.
```

Just assign these shortcuts to your preferred keybindings and you are good to go.

That might not be a solution for jumping directly to a terminal (e.g. like vims gt2) but it certainly is a start.

---

Edit: Just toyed around and found that you can also focus on a specific terminal. Just add any of these commands to your `keybindings.json` and you are good to go!

```
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex1
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex2
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex3
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex4
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex5
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex6
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex7
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex8
// - workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex9
```

e.g.
`{ "key": "yourkeybinding", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusAtIndex1"}`

Comment: This helped me a lot!! Thanks

Answer (score 68):

If you want something that might feel a bit more fluid than using arbitrary key bindings, you can get Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab working for both editor switching and terminal switching.

Open your keybindings file with `ctrl+shift+p` search for `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. Then add..

```
{ 
  "key": "ctrl+tab",            
  "command": "workbench.action.openNextRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
  "when": "editorFocus" 
},
{ "key": "shift+ctrl+tab",      
  "command": "workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup",
  "when": "editorFocus" 
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but you have a typo- instead of `workbench` you wrote `workspace` so the right value should be: `workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditorInGroup`

Comment: This seems to work differently with the current VSCode version:
In the Menu bar, go to Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. Search for 'focus terminal'. Double click 'Terminal: Focus Next Terminal' or 'Terminal: Focus Previous Terminal', input your shortcut, press Enter. Then right click the line and click 'Change When Expression' and input 'terminalFocus'. In my current VSCode version, there was no 'keyboard file' found.

Comment: Updates to this answer: Search for `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and only use the two terminalFocus entries. The editorFocus ones you'll probably want to leave as default for.

Comment: It is not working for me, any suggestion?

Answer (score 13):

Here's the solution I built that works well for me on OSX.

It mimics the same shortcuts used in the editor to open new files (cmd+n) and switch between tabs (cmd+left|right) and the same shortcuts work for terminals when that view is in focus.

Hit `cmd+shift+p` and type `keyboard` to find `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts File`

Add the following to the `keybindings.json` file and save it.

```
{
    "key": "cmd+alt+right",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+alt+left",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+n",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.new",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+w",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.kill",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

It also does the same for closing terminals (cmd+w)

Answer (score 5):

Based on [Haini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234000/haini) answer, Add the code below to your `keybindings.json`

```
{
  "key": "shift+up",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
  "key": "shift+down",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
  "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Now, you can switch between terminals using <kbd>shift + down</kbd> or <kbd>shift + up</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

on mac, <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>  worked for me.

this allows me to switch between different terminal instances when the terminal has focus. i use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to toggle focus between the terminal and editor.

source:

> Navigate between terminal groups using focus next ⇧⌘] and focus previous ⇧⌘[.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Answer (score 1):

To switch between terminal you can use below commands

On Mac

1. cmd + shift + [
2. cmd + shift + ]

This command will switch between terminal group. To find all commands:

command + shift + p (on mac)

Open keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

As for now it already switches tabs on the editor and terminal, just try ctrl + page up or ctrl + page down.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your keybindings.json file. This code sets up keybindings to switch between terminal tabs using "EasyMotion": Also install Easy motion from vs

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+`",
    "command": "easyMotion.quickMove",
    "args": {
        "inputType": "TerminalTabs",
        "repeatCountFormat": "Number",
        "matchFuzziness": "2"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

]