# Create New Macro (Shortcut) to Copy Paste and Execute Code in the Integrated Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

## The Problem

An operation I do a lot is to highlight/select code on the editors and then paste it on the integrated terminal to execute it. While I got pretty fast at using `Ctrl + c`, `Ctrl + backtick`, `Ctrl + Shift + v` and `Enter`, it's very annoying and repetitive. Is there a way to configure a macro or shortcut for this?

## A Solution (failed) Attempt

[This Github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37937) and [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065101/vs-code-key-binding-for-quick-switch-between-terminal-screens) show how to create a shortcut to toggle between different Integrated Terminals. I would like for something similar to happen in my case (I used `Ctrl + Shift + u` in the example below), e.g.:

```
[
    { 
        "key" : "ctrl+shift+k", 
        "command" : "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext" 
    },
    { 
        "key" : "ctrl+shift+j", 
        "command" : "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious" 
    },
    { 
        "key" : "ctrl+shift+u", 
        "command" : "ctrl+c+ctrl+`+ctrl+shift+v+enter" 
    },
]
```

Comment: Not really answering your question, but why not create a debugging configuration and run your code with F5? It would be better as you can use the debugging tools.

Comment: I haven't yet used VS Code's debugging tools very much (I only debug with `print`s and `log`s mostly), I should probably invest more time in it. But, with respect to your suggestions, wouldn't I need to configure the language I'm debugging and also press `Ctrl + Shift + d` first? The terminal is language independent (you have to add prefixes, I know...) and serves better for quick stuff. Though I agree that for debugging sessions the debugging tools are much better.

Comment: Start by reading VS Code docs on [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). You just need to setup launch and task configurations depending on your language and app. The configs tell VSCode where to find the codes, how to prepare it, and how to run it. F5 runs the most recent config, but you can setup multiple configs and select it from the Debug panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Without VS Code Extensions

There is a command : `workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText` which does what you want already and is not bound to any keychord by default.

[Just to see the `sendSequence` command]:

If you don't go another route, this keybinding will run the selected text in the terminal:

```
{
    "key": "alt+t",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "${selectedText}\u000D"
    }
},
```

The `\u000D` is a return.

** [Added by Phillippe] :::

## With a VS Code Extension (Macro Sequence Configurations)

VS Code currently doesn't allow concatenating shortcuts, so, if you want to execute the code on the Integrated Terminal *and* focus on it, you will have to install a macro extension.

There are several options for this. However, the suggested one is to use the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) (don't go for first results like [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros), some of them are *very* outdated).

To create the shortcut mentioned above, create a sequence of commands in your `settings.json` file:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [ // Copy Paste to the Integrated Terminal and also Focus on it
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.copyPasteTerminalAndFocus",
        "sequence": [
            {
                "command" : "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence", 
                "args" : {"text" : "${selectedText}\u000D"}
            },
            "workbench.action.terminal.focus"
        ]
    },
]
```

And then create a shortcut for it in the `keybindings.json` file:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.copyPasteTerminalAndFocus" }
},
```

Comment: Awesome. I wonder how you found that out... Are there simple logical steps or was it mostly experience? Also, one minor "issue" about your answer is that the focus continues on the editor and not on the terminal. How could I change the focus to the terminal (maybe this should be another shortcut actually)?

Comment: ctrl+`  (that's a backtick) will focus the terminal.  I've seen that command in the Release Notes - which I read thoroughly each month.  Otherwise you could try typing variuos keywords into the `Keyboard Shortcuts` window which list all the commands - so typing `run` would come up with a few commands and `runSelectedText` is one of them.

Comment: I use `Ctrl + backtick` quite a lot, but I was talking about creating a macro shortcut with what you did and `Ctrl + backtick`. Was there a reason for not accepting my edit suggestion? I thought it improved your answer with another option where you could concatenate shortcuts.

Comment: I can't recommend the `macros` extension which was in your proposed anymore. I used to use it a lot. But it hasn't been updated in two years and doesn't handle async operations properly - there are issues filed about it.  And an over 2 year old PR to fix it!  It just seems so easy to do the Ctrl+` that a macro seems overkill.  But I would accept an edit using a different macro extension.

Comment: Good point. I will investigate another option for macros tomorrow and see if I find something. But I still think mentioning would be worth, since the `macros` extension would be an extra option --- granted, I/you would mention the problems with `macros` extension in the edit.

Comment: I've added a new edit. See if you like it. Even if you don't I will grant you the answer (I really think some more information on the answer itself would be helpful to anyone who comes across this question). While you're here, I would like to invite to take a look at a [repo](https://github.com/psygo/vs_code) I created about (my) VS Code settings. See ya, and thanks again for the help.